# Postgres group by data hourly,then find the time difference from max and min createdAt and calculate their sum

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, aggregate-functions, date-arithmetic

I have a table like this :

```
p_id |      createdat      | pagetitle | sessionid |      text       | device  | deviceserial
------+---------------------+-----------+-----------+-----------------+---------+--------------
      | 2020-09-03 06:59:18 |           |           | Approve         | Android | 636363636890
      | 2020-09-03 08:40:10 |           |           | launchComponent | Android | 636363636890
      | 2020-09-03 08:40:11 |           |           | hi              | Android | 6625839827
      | 2020-09-03 08:45:11 |           |           | hi              | Android | 6625839827
      | 2020-09-03 08:43:10 |           |           | launchComponent | Android | 636363636890
      | 2020-09-03 08:50:11 |           |           | hi              | Android | 6625839827
      | 2020-09-03 08:47:10 |           |           | launchComponent | Android | 636363636890
      | 2020-09-03 08:53:11 |           |           | hi              | Android | 6625839827
      | 2020-09-03 08:50:10 |           |           | launchComponent | Android | 636363636890
      | 2020-09-03 08:55:11 |           |           | hi              | Android | 6625839827
      | 2020-09-03 08:52:10 |           |           | launchComponent | Android | 636363636890
      | 2020-09-03 09:00:11 |           |           | hi              | Android | 6625839827
      | 2020-09-03 08:55:10 |           |           | launchComponent | Android | 636363636890
      | 2020-09-03 09:05:11 |           |           | hi              | Android | 6625839827
      | 2020-09-03 08:59:10 |           |           | launchComponent | Android | 636363636890
      | 2020-09-03 09:07:11 |           |           | hi              | Android | 6625839827
      | 2020-09-03 09:01:10 |           |           | launchComponent | Android | 636363636890
      | 2020-09-03 09:09:11 |           |           | hi              | Android | 6625839827
      | 2020-09-03 09:03:10 |           |           | launchComponent | Android | 636363636890
      | 2020-09-03 09:09:11 |           |           | hi              | Android | 6625839828
      | 2020-09-03 09:03:10 |           |           | launchComponent | Android | 636363636891
      | 2020-09-03 09:13:11 |           |           | hi              | Android | 6625839828
```

I want to groupby data hourly and deviceserial.Then find the max and min value from hourly createdAt and then calculate the sum.
Thats my query I have tried:

```
Select deviceserial,DATE_PART('minute', max(createdat)::timestamp - min(createdat)::timestamp) AS time_difference,date_part('hour', createdat) as hr FROM json_table2  GROUP BY deviceserial,hr;
```

This is my result:

```
deviceserial | time_difference | hr
--------------+-----------------+----
 636363636891 |               3 |  9
 6625839832   |               0 | 11
 636363636890 |               0 |  6
 636363636890 |              19 |  8
 6625839830   |               0 | 10
 6625839830   |               0 | 12
 6625839835   |               0 | 10
 6625839833   |               0 | 12
 6625839828   |               4 |  9
 6625839832   |               0 | 10
 6625839835   |               0 | 11
 636363636890 |               2 |  9
 6625839827   |               9 |  9
 6625839833   |               0 | 11
 6625839827   |              15 |  8
```

I want to find something like this.It will be hourly sum of time differences(createdAt differences) groupby deviceserial:

```
deviceserial | time_difference | 
--------------+-----------------+----
 636363636890 |              21 |   
 6625839827   |              24 | 

And for other values as well...
```

Here I am trying to find the device usage of different deviceSerial.

Comment: hi, perhaps use subqueries for the `min` and `max` values?

Comment: You want the sum of the differences between the max and min within an hour?  That really doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @GordonLinoff,createdAt is value of event when it was created.Event is add to cart,edit and so on.I am trying to find the device usage per hour and add them together to find the total usage time of the device in 24H.So I am grouping data by deviceSerial and hourly.I don't know is it the right approach to find the device usage.

Comment: Thanks all of you.I will ask another question.I will explain there,what I want to achive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I follow you correctly, that's another level of aggregation on top of your existing query:

```
select deviceserial, sum(time_difference) as time_difference
from (
    select deviceserial,
        date_part('minute', max(createdat)::timestamp - min(createdat)::timestamp) as time_difference,
        date_trunc('hour', createdat) as hr 
    from json_table2  
    group by deviceserial, hr
) t
group by deviceserial
```

I changed the query to use `date_trunc()` instead of `date_part()`: the latter counts together records that happen at the same hour in different days, which I don't think you want.

While this may answer your immediate question, I wonder how useful the result is. You might want to ask another question, explaining what you are trying to do from the start.

Answer (score 2):

Use a second level of aggregation.

```
SELECT deviceserial,
       sum(time_difference) time_difference
       FROM (SELECT deviceserial,
                    extract(epoch FROM max(createdat) - min(createdat)) time_difference,
                    FROM json_table2
                    GROUP BY deviceserial,
                             date_part('hour', createdat)) x
       GROUP BY deviceserial;
```

And you should better use `extract()` rather than `date_part()` if you want the interval's length in minutes, not just the minute part of it. (Even if both yield the same result *here*, as the minimum and maximum are at most an hour apart. But if you one day chose to change the grouping to be by days for example, you'll get wrong results and probably wouldn't even notice at first.)

And you probably don't need to cast `min()` or `max()`, if `createdat` is of an appropriate type already.